# phpMyAdmin and XML export: the old way

Tags: xml, phpmyadmin

I recently updated my server in my hosting so I got a newer version of phpMyAdmin.

I use the XML export tool very often, but now I find that the format of the XML file that I got from my query is totally different, with field names as attributes instead of tag names.

I need the old way of export XML from a query back, **with field names as the tags of the XML nodes.** Why did they change this? This format is totally useless for me.

Is there anyway to keep the old fashioned way of XML export, that does not imply to make my own PHP script or so, just with phpMyAdmin and one single click as I used to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This changed a long time ago, with the release of phpMyAdmin 3.3.0 in 2010, so you must have had a very old version.

It's probably possible to modify the file `libraries/plugins/export/ExportXml.php` (or, better to modify a copy of that file), or maybe modify the old version from prior to version 3.3.0.

You could bring this up for discussion on the phpMyAdmin developer mailing list and perhaps get some assistance there.